# Copying down a range from cells above in VBA

Tags: excel, forms, vba

I have a formula that automatically populates cells by copying down from above and the following code works perfectly for the cell references that I require.

```
Dim lstRw As Long
Dim Rng As Range
lstRw = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
Set Rng = Range("A" & lstRw + 1)
Range("A" & lstRw & ":C" & lstRw & ":I" & lstRw & ":N" & lstRw).Copy Range("A" & lstRw + 1)
With Rng
```

However.. I also want the code to copy down a range from AW:BK..

I have tried the following:

```
Dim lstRw As Long
Dim Rng As Range
lstRw = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
Set Rng = Range("A" & lstRw + 1)
Range("A" & lstRw & ":C" & lstRw & ":I" & lstRw & ":N" & lstRw & "AW:BK" & lstRw).Copy Range("A" & lstRw + 1)
With Rng
```

But I keep getting compile errors!

Regards

Comment: run time error 1004. Method 'Range' of object'_Global' failed

Comment: If `lstRw` were 99, this is your range: `Range("A99:C99:I99:N99AW:BK99")`. See the issue yet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `"AW:BK"` to `"AW" & lstRw & ":BK" & lstRw`

Say your last row is row 10, to reference multiple columns of row 10 you would have to write `AW10:BK10` your code just needs to replicate this.

EDIT I only looked at the AW:BK portion initially. If you are trying to select columns A,C,I,N,AW:BK of the same row you need to separate them by commas not colons

```
range("A" & LstRw & ",C" & LstRw & ",I" & LstRw & ",N" & LstRw & ",AW" & LstRw & ":BK" & LstRw)
```

Comment: still getting the same error code with    "AW" & lstRw & ":BK" & lstRw

Comment: I tried this am having the same error..

would setting a new range in a different sub address it? What would I have to change to do this?

Comment: `Range(Replace("A0,C0,I0,N0,AW0:BK0", 0, LstRw))` tidies it up a bit.